# BSC Flashloan getting Pancake:Locked

Tags: solidity, bsc, flash-loans

im trying to get a flashloan in pancakeswap - BSC, but i'm getting locked from the locked modifier in the pair:

```
modifier lock() {
    require(unlocked == 1, 'Pancake: LOCKED');
    unlocked = 0;
    _;
    unlocked = 1;
}
```

this is my contract:

```
   function startArbitrage() external {
    IUniswapV2Router01 router = IUniswapV2Router01(router);

    address pairAddress = IUniswapV2Factory(address(0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73)).getPair(CAKE, WBNB);

    require(pairAddress != address(0), 'This pool does not exist');
    IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).swap(
      0, 
      10000000000000000000000, 
      address(this), 
      bytes('not empty')
    );
}


function pancakeCall(address _sender, uint _amount0, uint _amount1, bytes calldata _data) external {
    IUniswapV2Router01 pcRouter = IUniswapV2Router01(router);

    require(msg.sender == IUniswapV2Factory(address(0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73)).getPair(CAKE, WBNB), 'Unauthorized'); 

    

    uint amountToken = _amount1;

    IERC20 token = IERC20(WBNB);
    token.approve(address(router), type(uint256).max);

    uint amountRequired = amountToken;

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = WBNB;
    path[1] = CAKE;
    
    uint cakeReceived = pcRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountToken, amountRequired, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 10)[1];
    
    address[] memory path1 = new address[](2);
    path1[0] = CAKE;
    path1[1] = BUSD;
    uint busdReceived = pcRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(cakeReceived, cakeReceived, path1, address(this), block.timestamp + 10)[1];

    address[] memory path2 = new address[](2);
    path1[0] = BUSD;
    path1[1] = WBNB;
    uint wbnbReceived = pcRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(busdReceived, busdReceived, path2, address(this), block.timestamp + 10)[1];
    
    token.transfer(msg.sender, amountRequired);

}
```

This is an example tx:
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc/0xd26d8632a9a06834134e469bac5b1852c2139cf6c5d8218940bd6b02aac30891

Not sure where it is failing

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the tenderly trace the `swap` function in PancakePair is being called within another call to `swap` in the same PancakePair.

If you look at the `swap` function definition

```
function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external lock {
```

It is guarded by the `lock` modifier, which protect agains reentry

```
modifier lock() {
    require(unlocked == 1, 'Pancake: LOCKED');
    unlocked = 0;
    _;
    unlocked = 1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but why? my code makes only 1 call to swap? Is pancake internally borrowing from itself to fulfill my trade? if not I dont get why

Comment: `pancakeCall` calls `swapExactTokensForTokens` which calls `_swap` which calls `swap`. It is in the tenderly trace.

Comment: but then, how can I ask for a flash loan if pancake is LOCKED due to pancake calling swap itself?

Comment: So, if I ask for a LOAN on PCS I cant trade on PCS with that loan?

Comment: @redigaffi Well you cannot reentry the same Pair contract. In any case it is kinda of shady to do that from one of the tokens in the swap operation.

Comment: ahh so the issue is entering the same PancakePair, ok that makes more sense now